# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." with FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am working with the jQuery FullCalendar plugin. I import like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.print.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.css"></script>
```

When I load the pahe with Chrome, if I open console I can see this error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.css:8
```

So the error seems to be in css file of the FullCalendar plugin, in this line:

```
.fc {
direction: ltr;
text-align: left;
}
```

Why would that "." before "fc" be wrong? Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

It's a `.css` file, which means it's a Cascading Stylesheet and not a script. You want a `<link>` tag rather than a `<script>` one.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.css"/>
```

Attempting to load it using a `<script>` tag results in your CSS being interpreted as JavaScript, and throwing the error because it's invalid. You can't use a `.` at the start of a JavaScript identifier so it's not expecting to find one at that position in the "code".

Comment: Thanks for the succinct answer!

Comment: Thanks @Anthony Grist Its saved my time :)

Comment: Just ran into this today. Thanks!